# static buttons inside a scrollView android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am making an xml layout file consists of 3 parts:

- Part 1: some information and image about a place.
- Part 2: two horizontal `Button`s.
- Part 3: `RecyclerView` of some people reviews.

This is my layout file:

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="com.example.abdo.foodproject.OneItemFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.abdo.foodproject.OneItemFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/activity_item"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/oneitem_background_theme"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="13"
    >
    <LinearLayout>
    (...) <!--part 1-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  <!--part 2-->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/review_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reviews"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bestMeal_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:text="@string/best_meal"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  <!--part 3-->
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have the buttons fixed at my screen, at the top of the window, without losing their view from the scrolling.

Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Comment: Show your layout file

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Ok so what exactly is not working? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: i expect what when the scroll view works, and the part 1 disappear, those two buttons just stick to the top of my window and not move up and disappear too.

Comment: Where do you want them to be static? At the bottom or the top?

Comment: at the top of the window

Comment: Do you want them to **always** be sticked at the top?

Comment: no when part one dissapears only

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoordinatorLayout to achive such an affect.
CoordinatorLayout has 2 childs which one has also 2 childs as you wish

1. AppBarLayout: is a linear layout with vertical orientation. It's contents can disappear or pin according to *"app:layout_collapseMode"* attribute when scroll completed.

   - 1.1. CollapsingToolbarLayout: you can put your "part 1" view in this place with *app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"* to parallax when disappearing.
   - 1.2. Fixed view. LinearLayout: feel free to replace with your "part 2" view. This part will be pinned when scroll completed.
2. Scrollable view: it is RecyclerView in your example.

Final code should be similar like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <!--part 1-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <!--part 2-->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weight_sum="2">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/review_list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/reviews"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bestMeal_list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:text="@string/best_meal"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--part 3-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```